# How to a Hide Download Link

Tags: asp-classic, hyperlink, download, hide

I created a protected area in my website, where only registered users can logon to download a restricted application (exe). But they can copy the download link and make it available on internet, so I am trying to find the simplest way to hide the download link (using ASP classic, if possible).

Here is what I got so far: http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/download-manager-downloading-files-secure-location-classic-asp-65239.html. But when using this download manager, the exe application unexplainably looses its digital signing :(

Please, can anyone give me some ideas? Maybe using PHP or Flash?

Thanks!

Comment: simple solution: embed a one-time token in the download url. once that token's used, you record it as used, and never allow it to be used again.

Comment: @Marc B, I am trying to understand your idea... can you give me some example? Maybe a link where I can get more information? Thanks!

Comment: @Paruba You store some unique key (token) in your database, then use it as a `QueryString` parameter in the link you provide (suggest encoding it as [tag:Base64]), when the users accesses the page with the token you can check it with a call to the database then disable it (either delete or archive it). Beauty of this method is you can also do things like allow a set number of downloads then forbid anymore, all through storing bits of metadata against your token like `download count`, `last download` (datetimestamp)...possibilities are endless.

Comment: @Lankymart, I understood your sugestion, thank you! But I found a simpler way doing this, and will leave the answer for people that are looking for the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I found, using ASP classic:

```
<%
Option Explicit
Response.Buffer = True
If (not Session("Logged")) Then Response.End
Dim objFso
Dim objStream
Dim strFileName
Dim strFilePath
strFileName = "App.exe"
strFilePath = "d:\yoursitefolder\protectedfolder\"
Set objFso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFso.FileExists(strFilePath & strFileName) Then
  Response.AddHeader "Content-disposition", "filename=" & strFileName
  Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
  Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
  Response.AddHeader "Expires", "0"
  Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  objStream.Type = 1
  objStream.Open
  objStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath & strFileName
  Response.BinaryWrite(objStream.Read())
  objStream.Close
  Set objStream = Nothing
End If
Set objFso = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Not sure how that fixes your problem, unless I miss understood the question...actually I see they just have to have a valid session, sorry thought for some reason the link was coming from an uncontrollable source like an email for example. The simplest solutions are often the best.